# Замена текста в doc/rtf файле посредством PHP

Tags: doc, ms-word, rtf, php

Собственно сабж в самом заголовке.
Как реализовать замену текста в `doc/rtf` файле посредством PHP.
Допустим у меня есть `doc/rtf` файл с содержимым `"Привет {user} !"`.

Мне необходимо заменить слово `{user}` на `Вася`.

Гуглил до мозолей на пальцах - ничего кроме читалок не нашел.

Comment: Не стесняемся, делимся идеями.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Т.к. doc - закрытый бинарный формат, то напрямую открыть и модифицировать файл не получится.
 RTF проще, т.к. он по сути plain text с тэгами форматирлвания и можно использовать regex (с учетом того, что строка может быть представлена как последовательность кодовых значений символов ее составляющих).
Итого - для doc потребуется использование внешнмх программ или библиотек. Вероятно самый разумный способ - использование возможностей установленной копии ms office (через com) или, что лучше, openoffice. По программированию для ОО есть такой материал на русском, но для с++: http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/cpp/116151/