# Парсер документа Microsoft Word для PHP

Tags: ms-word, php

Друзья, подскажите годный парсер вордовских документов (.doc) для PHP. Или любой другой альтернативный способ получения html-текста.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [Текст любой ценой: WCBFF и DOC](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/php/72745/)
- [Замена текста в doc/rtf файле посредством PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/37674/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-doc-rtf-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC-php)